# visual studio code - debugging with inspector protocol

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS code for a bit and suddenly, today, it starter to behave strangely when I debug...

in the debug condole it says

```
Debugging with inspector protocol because Node.js v8.9.1 was detected.
node --inspect-brk=3193 app.js 
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:3193/c89636e0-f77a-40ab-9046-da1ddaaaf31c
```

and is keep stopping and looping on a specific function without me having put any breakpoint:

```
function createScript(code, options) {
  return new Script(code, options);
}
```

I don't know if I have deleted or modified by mistake anything.....

interesting enough if I run the code in the console, it runs without trowing errors... while with the debug it seems I cannot finish the debugging (keep looping)...

I noticed in the debug console the message above.... not sure if that is normal....

any suggestion???

thanks all

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Msg told you two things
First one is informational, tells you what protocol it's going with. `Inspector` is the latest and default protocol.
Second one looping on `createScript` is a problem. Is it from your own file or a package file?